# How to remove margins after installing React Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I'm using React to create an admin page.
I installed the react bootstrap to use the component.
I did as I was [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/), and there were left and right margin in the container just below the `RootView`.

I want to get rid of this. Thank you for the solution.

Below is the image of a margin.

[image]

I want to get rid of the margin marked in red.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the `margin` on the container? It is built into Bootstrap by default, and Bootstrap projects typically *want* to make use of it. If you're not looking to use such a system, then Bootsrap may not be the best framework.

Comment: Hi LovePig, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Obsidian Age You're right. I think I should go with this margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this to CSS:

```
.container{
  margin-right : 0 !important;
  margin-left : 0 !important;
 }
```

in case it didn't work, I suspect `padding` will do the job:

```
.container{
  margin-right : 0 !important;
  margin-left : 0 !important;
  padding-right : 0 !important;
  padding-left : 0 !important;
 }
```

Comment: I tried. right-margin was successfully removed. width is set at (960,720,540)px. This is assumed to be the size for the flex of the bootstrap. I think I should give up....

Comment: what version of bootstrap you're using?

Comment: using version is 1.0.0-beta.12.
i'm added "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12", in "dependencies" in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is adding [`fluid`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#container-props) prop on `Container`.

> **fluid** - Allow the Container to fill all of its available horizontal space.

```
<Container fluid>
   ...
</Container>
```

Comment: I tried. right-margin was successfully removed. width is set at (960,720,540)px. This is assumed to be the size for the flex of the bootstrap. I think I should give up...

Comment: have you added correct `bootstrap.css`? If you are using `react-bootstrap v0.32.4` then you need `bootstrap 3` and if you'r using  `react-bootstrap v1.0.0-beta.12` then you need `bootstrap 4`.

Comment: i'm added "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12", in "dependencies" in package.json. 
and added import "bootstrap/dist/cs/bootstrap.min.cs"; to index.js rendering the RootView;

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
  margin-right : 0px;
  margin-left : 0px;
 }
```

add this in your custome css file